# This picture has some hidden message. What is it?

Tags: mathematics, cipher

[image]

This picture was uploaded for the Olympiads of Medicine, from Porto. While the answer might be in portuguese, I don't find it likely.

I tried some Caesar Cyphers, I assumed the colours represented the letters that'll go into the final message, the arrows some sort of permutation of the letters and the backwards B the cypher key.

Comment: Why the mathematics tag?

Comment: @tilper well, it's probably cryptography based. That's math, no?

Comment: Right, but AFAIK that tag isn't generally used when the only math-related component is cryptography, so just wondering if there was an additional math piece somehow.

Comment: Is this for an [ongoing competition](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1674/questions-from-on-going-contests/1675#1675)?

Comment: @IanMacDonald, it was a friend of mine who shared the problem with me. I don't know if it's part of a competition

Comment: It looks to me as if it may be from a competition -- but probably not an ongoing one, since this appears to be a regularly occurring event that happens in March and/or April.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I figured it out using the AtBash cipher, it looks like that is what the arrows mean, as for the backwards B and the paint icon...I have no idea.  The answer is (partly) in Portuguese.